# Want multiple Rows from 1 Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, rdbms

I have a table in a SQL Server like this (example):

| ID | ARTICLE | ARTTEXT | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 | Test1 | 5 |
| 2 | 324644 | blabla | 1 |
| 3 | 765456 | nanana | 12 |

Now these items are to be labelled. I.e. each copy needs a label. I then do this via the SSRS.

So I need from ID 1 5 labels, ID 2 1, ID 3 12.

Now the question is what does the select look like to get 5 rows from ID 1, 1 row from ID 2 and 12 rows from ID 3.

I guess a CTE, but it's not clear to me how to get x times the records

I look forward to your ideas.

Comment: Why do you want to return 5 rows if count is 5, and not just one?

Comment: i need the labels according to the number of the quantity. the print labels are then affixed per element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a Tally over the (far slower) rCTE solution. I use an inline tally here. If you need more than 100 rows, simply add more cross joins to `N` in the CTE defined as `Tally` (each cross join increases the maximum number of rows by a factor or 10).

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int,
                            Article int,
                            Arttext varchar(15),
                            [Count] int);
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES(1,123456,'Test1',5),
      (2,324644,'blabla',1),
      (3,765456,'nanana',12);

GO

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX([Count]) FROM dbo.YourTable)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2) --100 rows, add more cross joins for more rows
SELECT YT.ID,
       YT.Article,
       YT.Arttext,
       T.I AS [Count]
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN Tally T ON YT.[Count] >= T.I
ORDER BY YT.ID,
         T.I;
GO


DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to multiply the number of rows based on `count`.  One method uses a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select id, article, arttext, count
      from t
      union all
      select id, article, arttext, count - 1
      from cte
      where count > 1
     )
select id, article, arttext
from t;
```

If the count exceeds 100, then you want `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

Comment: thanks for this.

but it doesn't work like this. the result is the same as a normal 
select * from t


i have no idea how to use COUNT as a loop

Comment: Did you intend to write a recursive CTE gordon? You did not select from the CTE so it is not using recursion.